# Problema com heranças e classes no Ruby

Tags: ruby

Eu tenho esse código. Não consigo imprimir a variável do editor no método incrementNameTitle, ela não está sendo exibida. O resultado é o seguinte:

Editora: Em Chamas - Collins!

```
class Editora 
   attr_accessor :nameEditora
   def initialize(nameEditora)
      @nameEditora = nameEditora
   end
   def incrementNameTitle
      puts "Editora #{@nameEditora}: #{@title} - #{@author}!"
   end
end
   
class Book < Editora
   attr_accessor :title, :author
   def initialize(title, author)
      @title = title
      @author = author
   end
end

book = Book.new("Em Chamas", "Collins")
editora = Editora.new('LucasLivros')

puts book.incrementNameTitle
```

Comment: Você instanciou as classes separadamente, então por que utilizar herança? Um livro **é uma** editora?

Comment: Hum, estou aprendendo POO então não entendi direito seu comentário. Como eu posso acessar as variáveis title e author na classe Book?

Comment: Herança deve ser utilizado para criar subtipos, ou uma especialização de uma abstração. Ao fazer `Book` herdar de `Editora` você basicamente está definindo que um livro é um subtipo de uma editora. Isso não faz sentido. Talvez o que faria mais sentido aí é composição - e quem sabe você pode ler mais a fundo sobre ela.

Comment: Ok! Muito obrigado!

Comment: Como eu poderia fazer pra conseguir acessar o nome da editora junto ao nome e autor do livro?

Answer (score 0):

Como o Woss comentou na sua pergunta, você está a fazer uma herança, quando na verdade, o que você precisa aqui é uma composição.

Você pode alterar o construtor do livro para receber uma editora:

```rb
class Book
   # code omitted...
   def initialize(title, author, editora)
     # code omitted...
```

Depois disso, você define o método `incrementNameTitle` em `Book`, como agora você está a receber a editora no construtor, você terá acesso ao que quiser.